# Angular - disable only one row in a table

Tags: html, angular

I am using an event emitter to get the value of disabledReason inside the `*ngFor`:

```
<tr *ngFor="let row of people; let i = index; trackBy: trackById">
  <td id="people-table-{{i}}">
    <fieldset [disabled]="disabledReason">
      <input  type="text" id="people-table-text{{i}}">
    </fieldset>
  </td>
</tr>
```

The problem is that the input for every row of the table gets disabled and not just the row which is required.

Comment: The correct approach, to me, would be having a `row` property (either a getter, either a valorized property) that determines whether that row specifically is disabled. What is `disabledReason` anyway?

Comment: a boolean value

Comment: if you know the index of  row  which you want to disable then you will do like  [disabled]="i === disableIndex"

Comment: make that first row hardcoded

Answer (score 3):

Use an index instead of a boolean value for `disabledReason` and compare it to the row index to be disabled:

```
disabledReason = 3; // will disable row index 3
```

```
<tr *ngFor="let row of people; let i = index; trackBy: trackById">
  <td id="people-table-{{i}}">
    <fieldset [disabled]="disabledReason === i">
      <input  type="text" id="people-table-text{{i}}">
    </fieldset>
  </td>
</tr>
```